# Adding more than one method to a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, methods

Having read about JS objects I believe I can adds methods in the following way:

```
var activity = {
name: null,
start: null,
finish: null,
alarm: function (x) {
    if (x === this.start) {
    return true;
    }
    if (x !== this.start) {
    return false;
    }
}       
colour: function (x) {
    if (x < this.start) { 
    return "red"; 
    }
    if (x > this.start && x < this.finish) { 
    return "green"; 
    }
    if (x > this.finish) { 
    return "grey"; 
    }   
}

};
```

When I run this through JSFiddle it says

Expected '(end)' instead saw ':'.

Next to the line with "colour" in it.

I'm not sure what I have done wrong?

Comment: use a comma to separate properties and methods of objects.

Comment: What is the best category to flag typo questions such as this as?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: run your code through a syntax checker...can do it online even ...paste/click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just missing a comma to separate `alarm` and `colour`:

```
},  // <--- here
colour: function (x) {
```

Same as you had between `finish` and `alarm`:

```
finish: null,
alarm: function (x) {
```

With `Object` literals, a comma is always needed to separate `key:value` pairs, even when the *value* is an entire `function`.

Comment: Thanks for kindly pointing this out.